# The Microsoft Graph API: List post attachments API doesn't work

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I followed this [document](http://graph.microsoft.io/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/post_list_attachments) and wrote the code as below, but it response 405(method not allowed), error message is "The OData request is not supported.".

```
function getAttachment(groupId, threadId, postId) {
    HttpClient.get({
        url: "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/" + groupId + "/threads/" + threadId + "/posts/" + postId + "/attachments"
    }).then(function (resp) {

    });
};
```

Is there something wrong in the code?

Comment: Could you try the beta api instead of v1.0 ? do you get the same error.

Comment: Yes I did, but also got the same error message.

Comment: i know this might sound odd, but since you've got an http 405 response, did you try sending a POST (or PUT, etc.) instead and see what happens?

Comment: It could be that this endpoint is currently unsupported. Check the following GitHub thread for updates: https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/72#issuecomment-163311210

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct, it's a bug in the Graph API. A fix for it is being rolled out and should be widely available in about a month.